# Compartilhamento de dados entre aplicativos android

Tags: java, android

Criei um aplicativo que funciona como uma agenda, onde é possível cadastrar contatos com mais alguns campos com relação às agendas que vem pré instaladas no dispositivo.

Minha dúvida é, se é possível compartilhar os dados cadastrados com outros aplicativos, por exemplo o whatsapp usar o nome do contato cadastrado (o cadastro desses contatos tem um campo telefone)? Se é possível,  como?

Comment: Os dados são cadastrados onde?

Comment: No banco sqlite

Comment: A resposta do kakamg0 vai no sentido do que pretende? Se não explique melhor porque eu não entendi exactamente o que pretende.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É possível compartilhar os dados com outros aplicativos instalados utilizando [`ACTION_SEND`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEND) quando você cria um `Intent`.

Você pode fazer dessa forma:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.send_to)));
```

Você pode ler mais em [Sending Simple Data to Other Apps](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html?hl=pt-br) e [WhatsApp FAQ](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/28000012)

Também é possível adicionar um item no menu para fazer o compartilhamento utilizando [Adding an Easy Share Action](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/shareaction.html?hl=pt-br)

Comment: Obrigado ajudo muito, mas ainda não possui minha resposta. Eu teria que mandar meu banco pro app do whats sempre que houver um cadastro, alteração ou exclusão? E sim eu teria que fazer um `select` e mandar um `ArrayList`?

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam Acho que não entendi bem a sua pergunta. Você quer que o usuário possa compartilhar um contato do seu app para uma conversa/grupo no whats ou que todos os contatos cadastrados no seu app estejam disponíveis para o usuário abrir o whats e iniciar uma nova conversa ou adicionar em um grupo?

Comment: todos os contatos cadastrados no seu app estejam disponíveis para o usuário abrir o whats e iniciar uma nova conversa ou adicionar em um grupo

Comment: A resposta que coloquei seria para o primeiro caso, para que os contatos do seu app fique disponível para o whats você deverá cadastrá-los na lista de contatos do telefone. O whats lê sua lista de contatos e verifica quais estão cadastrados no whats para que você possa usar ele dentro do WhatsApp como descrito no [FAQ](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/20971813/?category=5245250).

Comment: Para que você possa cadastrar os contatos do seu no telefone você pode utilizar o código de https://stackoverflow.com/a/10204543 ou https://stackoverflow.com/a/40147115 ou [Modifying Contacts Using Intents](https://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/modify-data.html)

Comment: então eu teria que cadastrar na meu banco e usar um desses para cadastrar na agenda telefônica padrão do usuário?

Comment: Exatamente, aí quando WhatsApp ler a agenda padrão do usuário ele irá reconhecer os números que estão cadastrados dentro do WhatsApp e os seus contatos estarão disponíveis para ser utilizado dentro do whats.

Comment: Obrigado. Acho que meu aplicativo não vai ter essa facilidade